# No class def found error unable to resolve this

Tags: cucumber, resources, karma-runner, noclassdeffounderror, loader

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcjI5.png)[No classDefError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHY7X.png)

added few dependency also but not working